# Variable implemented in a function name

Tags: function, powershell, variables, active-directory

Since I couldn't find a solution for my problem anywhere, I'll ask it here:
basically, I am trying to create a basic function for AD where I have a variable inside of the function name - in my case, its this one:

```
"Get-AD$FilterItem"
```

Where `$FilterItem` would be User, Computer, Group etc., so I don't have to make the same function for every single AD item.

But I can't get it working, it always gives me

> ...: The term 'get-ad$filteritem' is not recognized...

what to do?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This looks very much like an [X-Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What do you think you need this for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quick reply

```
$i="user"
$f="get-ad$i"
&$f username
```

Comment: thanks, simple call didnt come to mind for me somehow x)

Answer (score 2):

You can create `New-Item` to the Function provider. You'd better also create a closure instead of simple script block, so you can have the value also available inside the function:

```
$x = "Foo"
New-Item -Path Function: -Name "Shout$x" -value { write-host "$x" }.GetNewClosure()
$x = "Bar"
New-Item -Path Function: -Name "Shout$x" -value { write-host "$x" }.GetNewClosure()
ShoutFoo
ShoutBar
```